# Retrieve an element inside an object collection

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making board game, and I want that when I click in one of the places I turn them red. I have this array of `divs`, but I don't know how to retrieve the element given the `number` to turn it red. How can I do that, I'm trying to use `.element` but it's not working

```js
var number = 3;
const board = [];
const boardWidth = boardHeight = 10;

(function() {
  const boardElement = document.getElementById('board');
  for (var y = 0; y < boardHeight; ++y) {
    var row = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < boardWidth; ++x) {
      var cell = {};
      cell.element = document.createElement('div');
      boardElement.appendChild(cell.element);
      row.push(cell);
    }
    board.push(row);
  }
  painting();
})();

function painting() {
  board[number][number].element.style.backgroundcolor = 'red';
}
```

```css
#board {
  width: calc(10 * 30px);
  margin: auto;
}

#board div {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Comment: can you please create a demo?

Comment: I've just edited

Comment: as a side note, the CSS property name to be used in JavaScript is `backgroundColor` and `not background-color`

Comment: I know you already accepted an answer, but I put together a config driven approach to your board. I thought you might find it useful. If so, yay! If not, no worries. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code look very confusing. `board` is an element and you are using it as an array.
Next come some code. I hope this is what you need:

```js
let cellW = 100;
let cellH = 100;

function init(){ 
  
let boardArray = [];
let bStyle = window.getComputedStyle(board, null);
let bWidth = parseInt(bStyle.getPropertyValue("width"));
let bHeight = parseInt(bStyle.getPropertyValue("height"));

  
  for (let y = 0; y < bHeight; y+=cellH) {
        let row = [];
        for (let x = 0; x < bWidth; x+=cellW) {
            let cell = {};
            cell.element = document.createElement('div');
            cell.element.style.width = cellW +"px";
            cell.element.style.height = cellH +"px";
            board.appendChild(cell.element);
            row.push(cell);
        }
    boardArray.push(row);
}

}
init();



let cells = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#board div"));


cells.map( cell => {
  cell.addEventListener("click", e =>{
    cell.style.background = "red"
  })
})
```

```css
#board{width: 1000px; height:500px; display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;}
#board div{outline:1px solid;}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

UPDATE:

I understand that you need to make the 4-th cell in the cells array red:

```js
    var number = 3;
    const board = [];
    const boardWidth = 10, boardHeight = 10;

    function init() {
        const boardElement = document.getElementById('board');
        for (var y = 0; y < boardHeight; ++y) {
            var row = [];
            for (var x = 0; x < boardWidth; ++x) {
                var cell = {};
                cell.element = document.createElement('div');
                boardElement.appendChild(cell.element);
                row.push(cell);
            }
            board.push(row);
        } 
      

      board[number][number].element.style.background = "red"
    }

window.addEventListener("load", init);
```

```css
#board {
        width: calc(10 * 30px);
        margin: auto;
    }

    #board div {
        background-color: black;
        border: 1px solid white;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```

Comment: This is almost what I want. I want to pass a number like in the code and turn it into red. Can you help with that code that I've just edited? There's some way to get the element just like 'board[number][number]'

Comment: My intention was to see this like a matrix, so board[3][3] would print the 34th cell. But this can work, thanks.

Comment: Please take a look again ( the second snippet )

Answer (score 0):

I've addressed all of your issues but thought you might be interested in making things configurable. I reworked your code to make things config driven.

This will:

1. Take a config (or not) and merge it with a default config.
2. Build your board dynamically based on config values v. setting the dimensions via CSS
3. Allows for cell toggle (select/unselect) and matric position assignments

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

  const extend = function(target, config, defaults){
    defaults && extend(target, defaults);

    if(target && config && typeof(config) === 'object'){
      for(const i in config){
        target[i] = config[i];
      }
    }

    return target;
  };

  function Game(config){
    const defaultConfig = {
      boardElement: '#board',
      // if a single digit is passed it will be duplicated for pos y 3 => 3,3
      startPosition: 3,
      cellSize: 30,
      boardWidth: 10,
      boardHeight: 10      
    };

    // merge the default and user-defined config into a new config
    this.config = extend({}, config || {}, defaultConfig);
    // cache ref to your board element    
    this.boardElement = document.querySelector(this.config.boardElement);
    // stores our collection of board items
    this.board = [];
    // draw the board
    this.draw();
    // set initial marker
    if(this.config.startPosition){
      if(this.config.startPosition instanceof Array){
        this.paint.apply(this, this.config.startPosition);
      }else{
        this.paint(this.config.startPosition);
      }
    }

    return this;
  }

  extend(Game.prototype, {
    draw(){  
      for (let y = 0; y < this.config.boardHeight; ++y) {
        const row = [];

        for (var x = 0; x < this.config.boardWidth; ++x) {
          const element = document.createElement('div');

          const cell = {
            element,
            position: { 
              x: x + 1, 
              y: y + 1 
            }   
          };
          // set cell width and height
          element.style.height = element.style.width = `${this.config.cellSize}px`;
          // handle selecting/unselecting cells
          element.addEventListener('click', () => this.paint(cell.position.x, cell.position.y));
          
          this.boardElement.appendChild(cell.element);

          row.push(cell);
        }

        this.board.push(row);
      }
      // set board width and height
      this.boardElement.style.width = `${this.config.boardWidth * this.config.cellSize}px`;
    },
    paint(x, y){
      if(y === undefined){
        y = x;
      }

      const element = this.board[y-1][x-1].element;

      if(element){
        const isSelcted = element.style.backgroundColor === 'red';
        element.style.backgroundColor = isSelcted ? 'black' : 'red';    
      }
    }
  });  

  new Game({
    startPosition: [5,4],
    boardWidth: 8,
    boardHeight: 8
  });
});
```

```css
#board {
  margin: auto;
}

#board div {
  background-color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="board"></div>
```